# Hiding Errors When Using Get-ADGroup

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working on a script that will build a new group if it doesn't exist.  I'm using Get-ADGroup to make sure the group doesn't exist using the following command:

```
$group = get-adgroup $groupName -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue
```

But when I do I get the following error (I removed any domain specific data from the error):

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity: '*group name*' under: '*domain*'.
At U:\Scripts\Windows\Create-FolderAccessGroup.ps1:23 char:24
+ $group = get-adgroup <<<< $groupName -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (y:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: ''.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

I assumed setting ErrorAction and WarningAction to SilentlyContinue would keep this error from being displayed but it hasn't.

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer because I have no idea if it will work or not and I can't test it right now, but try piping it to Out-Null.

Comment: @EBGreen so `$group = get-adgroup $groupName | out-null`?

Comment: That is what I would try, but as I say I'm not sure that it will work.

Comment: Good thing I didn't put it as an answer then :)

Comment: @EBGreen - that is for output. For example if you do `"blah" | out-null`, the blah wont be passed to the pipeline ( or console) Nothing to do with errors / exceptions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 try {get-adgroup <groupname>}
  catch  {
      <make new group>
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, small note, if you don't want the output of get-adgroup dumped to the console, use $x = get-adgroup <groupname>

Comment: You can also just redirect the output to $null, or pipe it to out-null.

Answer (score 24):

I find that this works best:

```
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $GroupName}
```

If the filter returns no results, then $Group is simply set to $null and no error message is generated.  Also, since a SAM account name must be unique in Active Directory, there is no risk of $Group being set to an array of more than one object.

I find that using -Filter to get the group rather than -Identity works really well when checking for the existence of groups (or users) in If statements. For example:

```
If (Get-ADGroup -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $GroupName})
{
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $ListOfUserSamAccountNames
}
Else
{
    Write-Warning "Users could not be added to $GroupName because $GroupName
    does not exist in Active Directory."
}
```

I find that is a lot easier to deal with logically (if the group exists, add the users; if not, display a message) than mjolinor's suggestion of try/catch with using the Get-ADGroup cmdlet with the -Identity parameter. Consider the try/catch method of doing the same as above, using the -Identity parameter:

```
Try
{
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupName
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Members $ListOfUserSamAccountNames
}
Catch
{
    Write-Warning "Users could not be added to $GroupName because $GroupName
    does not exist in Active Directory."
}
```

You see if *any* of the commands in the try block throws a terminating error. If one does, it means the group doesn't exist and will move on and process the command(s) in the catch block. It will work, but I don't think try/catch here flows as well, logically, in comparison to if/else.

Don't get me wrong, mjolinor is a PowerShell genius. It's just that in this case I don't think his solution is the best one.

Comment: I also prefer using -filter which makes for much cleaner code.  I always see people using try/catch too frequently when they should be thinking of more elegant strategies like this one.

Answer (score 6):

@mjolinor gives the good answer, but I think some explanation can also help.

Windows PowerShell provides two mechanisms for reporting errors: one mechanism for *terminating errors* and another mechanism for *non-terminating* errors.

Internal CmdLets code can call a `ThrowTerminatingError` method when an error occurs that does not or should not allow the cmdlet to continue to process its input objects. The script writter can them use exception to catch these error.

Internal CmdLets code can call a `WriteError` method to report *non-terminating* errors when the cmdlet can continue processing the input objects. The script writer can then use `-ErrorAction` option to hide the messages.

Comment: Thanks, mjolinor has the technically correct answer and your explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I also had this problem and solved it like this:

If (Get-ADObject -Filter {objectClass -eq "Group -and samAccountName -eq "groupname"}) { //do stuff// }

Answer (score 0):

try {New-ADGroup -Name "$NameGROUP -GroupScope Global -Path "$PathOU"} catch {    }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).