# Using try/catch blocks with Lync 2010 cmdlets in powershell

Tags: powershell, lync-2010

I've written a function to wrap the the new-cssipdomain cmdlet with a try/catch block incase the sip domain already exists. 
Code is:

```
function LHP-AddSIPDomain
{
   param ( [string] $SIPDomain)
   try
   {
      New-cssipdomain -id $SIPDomain
   }
   catch
   {   
      Write-host "Lync specific exception occured adding SIP domain"
      Write-host "Exception String:"+$_.Exception.Message
      exit
   }
}
LHP-AddSIPDOmain -SipDomain "Test206.com"
```

The output when the domain already exists is:

```
New-CsSipDomain : "SipDomain" with identity "Test206.com" already exists. To modify
the existing item, use the Set- cmdlet. To create a new item, use a different
identity. Parameter name: Identity
At S:\Scripts\LHP-AddSIPDomain.ps1:33 char:26
+           New-cssipdomain <<<<  -id $SIPDomain
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Test206.com:String) [New-CsSipDomain],
ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :
InvalidIdentity,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Xds.NewOcsSipDomainCmdlet
```

This should be caught by the try/catch block.
I've tried adding the [system.exception] to the catch statement. I'ev also tried setting  $erroraction=”Stop”. Neither made any different, the try/catch statement seems to be being ignored. I've used this type of code structure to capture errors from the new-aduser cmdlet and this seemed to work ok.

I have also considerd and tried using hte get-cssipdomin cmdlet first to check if the sip domain already exists, but I have a similar problem in that if you call get-cscsipdomain with a domain that doesn't exist it throws an error which I don't seem to be able to catch.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY:

```
try
   {
      New-cssipdomain -id $SIPDomain -ERRORACTION SilentlyContinue
   }
```

Maybe the command it self got a try/catch for  errors.

Comment: Excellent, problem solved! 
Turns out the error was non-terminating so the $ErrorAction variable didn't affect it. I recevied another suggestion of setting the $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop".
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307127/hiding-errors-when-using-get-adgroup/6314294#6314294). It explains why try/catch is sometime not working.

Can't you just write :

```
$Res = New-cssipdomain -id $SIPDomain -ERRORACTION SilentlyContinue
```

And test the value of $Res ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error you get is not a terminating error and that's why you can't catch it. Try to set the ErrorAction value to 'stop', that will make the error a terminating error and you'll be able to catch it in the catch block.