# Why does an error still show when I specify -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue?

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\Users\ad_ctjares> Stop-Transcript -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
Transcription has not been started. Use the start-transcript command to start transcription.
Stop-Transcript : An error occurred stopping transcription: The console host is not currently transcribing.
At line:1 char:16
+ Stop-Transcript <<<<  -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Stop-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopTranscriptCommand
```

The code says it all.

Comment: Don't know, but there's a bug filed on Connect about it, together with a workaround: http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/549321/start-stop-transcript-ignores-erroraction

Comment: Thanks - that led me to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307127/hiding-errors-when-using-get-adgroup, where I found out I need to use `try { } catch { }` because `-ErrorAction` doesn't affect Terminating Errors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ErrorAction` ubiquitous parameter can be used to silence non-terminating errors using the parameter value `SilentlyContinue` and it can be used to convert non-terminating errors to terminating errors using the parameter value `Stop`.  However it can't help you ignore terminating errors and in this case Stop-Transcript is throwing a terminating error.  If you want to ignore, use a try/catch e.g.:

```
try { Stop-Transcript } catch {}
```

Comment: Any full list about terminating errors ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545429/erroractionpreference-and-erroraction-silentlycontinue-for-get-pssessionconfigur

Answer (score 3):

You can use Trap {Continue} Stop-Transcript instead to avoid any errors.