# ErrorActionPreference and ErrorAction SilentlyContinue for Get-PSSessionConfiguration

Tags: powershell, error-handling, silent

My case:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
"1 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
Get-ChildItem NoSuchFile.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
"2 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
Get-ChildItem NoSuchFile.txt -ErrorAction Stop;
"3 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
```

Output:

> 1 - Stop;
>   2 - Stop;
>   and display an error...

Now,

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
"1 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
(Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "MyShellUri" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
"2 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
```

Output:

> 1 - Stop;
>   and display an error...

Why doesn't work -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) for Get-PSSessionConfiguration ?

**Update:**

Now,

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
"1 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
(Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "MyShellUri" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
"2 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
```

Output:

> 1 - Continue;
>   2 - Continue;

Now,

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
"1 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
(Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "MyShellUri" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
"2 - $ErrorActionPreference;"
```

Output:

> 1 - SilentlyContinue;
>   2 - SilentlyContinue;

This [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198023/why-does-an-error-still-show-when-i-specify-erroraction-silentlycontinue):

The `ErrorAction` ubiquitous parameter can be used to silence non-terminating errors using the parameter value `SilentlyContinue` and it can be used to convert non-terminating errors to terminating errors using the parameter value `Stop`.  However it can't help you ignore terminating errors and in this case Stop-Transcript is throwing a terminating error.  If you want to ignore, use a try/catch e.g.:

```
try { Stop-Transcript } catch {}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A solution for me:

```
$old_ErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
if((Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "MyShellUri" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
   WriteTraceForTrans "The session configuration MyShellUri is already unregistered."
}
else {        
   #Unregister-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "MyShellUri" -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
}
$ErrorActionPreference = $old_ErrorActionPreference
```

Or use try-catch

```
try { 

(Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "MyShellUri" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

} 
catch {

}
```

Comment: i didn't know `-ErrorAction Stop` is still needed for `catch` to get the exception :|

Comment: @AceMark it depends on the command.  Some commands throw terminating errors by default, and others don't.  To make things more complex, some dotnet errors *become* terminating when wrapped in a `try{}` block.  Best to be explicit.  I'm not sure what the standard is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that's an "unhandled exception", meaning the cmdlet itself hasn't been coded to recognize and handle that exception.  It blew up without ever getting to run it's internal error handling, so the -ErrorAction setting on the cmdlet never came into play.

Answer (score 1):

[Tip #2](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-2)

Can't you use the classical `2>` redirection operator.

```
(Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "MyShellUri" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 2> $NULL
if(!$?){
   'foo'
}
```

I don't like errors so I avoid them at all costs.