# Throw exceptions when errors happens inside a function

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm writing a PowerShell script with a try-catch that calls a bunch of functions.

```
function A {
  # exceptions here won't trigger the catch
}

function B {}

try {
  # exceptions here will trigger the catch

  A
  B
} catch {
  # handle errors
}
```

How do I get the functions to throw the exceptions upstream by default without writing a try catch block inside every functions?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're expecting. Where these exceptions should be handled?

Comment: Take a look at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545429/erroractionpreference-and-erroraction-silentlycontinue-for-get-pssessionconfigur)

Comment: Well, looks like it's working after all. I was having the problem where exceptions that happens inside a function doesn't trigger the catch block outside of it. But it's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you are looking for capturing error of all the function without multiple try-catch. In this scenario, you can use an error logging mechanism to handle it:

```
function logger($val1 , $val2)
{
  try
  {
    echo $val1 $val2
    if ($val1 -eq 'Fail')
    { 
      "Wrong Input passed so it was logged as error" + $val1 | out-file -Filepath $logfile -append
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    $_.Exception.Message | out-file -Filepath $logfile -append
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what exceptions your trying to throw but if you just manually want to throw and error to stop the script use the throw command.