# Understanding Powershell Try Catch

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I am having issues understanding the use of the try, catch statement.

I want to use it as a general error detection case so that is there are any issues in the given function the script will output "Server Offline"

The below snippet queries the WMI object on a server for it's list of HDD's and formats it into a table. If there server or WMI is not available I want to have "Server Offline" appended to the txt output file.

Currently the catch statement is never invoked when there is an error.

Can try catch be used this way?

```
try {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName  $server   | ft $server,deviceid,@{Label="Size(GB)";Expression={($_.Size/ 1gb) -as [int]}},@{Label="FreeSpace(Mb)";Expression={($_.FreeSpace/1mb) -as [int]}} -auto  | Out-File  c:\temp\ServersHDDAudit_OUTPUT-$a-$b.txt -Append

}
catch {
    $server + ": Server Offline" | Out-File  c:\temp\ServersHDDAudit_OUTPUT-$a-$b.txt -Append 
}
```

Samuel

Answer (score 3):

You'll find the information in one of my [other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6314294/608772), but when you write a CmdLet in PowerShell you can decide to throw exception or manage the error. `Get-WmiObject`  manage the errors so it writes the error and return a value. You can ask it to "silently continue" and throw your own exception.

```
try
{
  $ld = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName  $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  if ($ld -ne $null)
  {
    $ld | ft $server,deviceid,@{Label="Size(GB)";Expression={($_.Size/ 1gb) -as [int]}},@{Label="FreeSpace(Mb)";Expression={($_.FreeSpace/1mb) -as [int]}} -auto  | Out-File  c:\temp\ServersHDDAudit_OUTPUT-$a-$b.txt -Append
  }
  else
  {
    throw $Error[0].exception.Message
  }
}
catch
{
  $server + ": $_" | Out-File  c:\temp\ServersHDDAudit_OUTPUT-$a-$b.txt -Append 
}
```

**Remark** : you can set `-ErrorAction Stop` parameter to have a exception thrown by `Get-WmiObject`. Or you can specify `$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"` if you want that all Cdmlet throw Exception on errors.

Comment: That last line `$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"` is very important and convenient for `try {} catch {}` to work as expected. That if anything inside the `try {}` causes any error it will cause the `catch{}` to be run.

Answer (score 1):

Try/catch works only with terminating errors. In my experience, 99% of errors produced by `Get-WmiObject` are not terminating so catch wont have any effect in this case.

One thing you can do is make the any error thrown by the command a terminating error, you can do that with the `-ErrorAction Stop`. Passing 'stop' will make the error a terminating error allowing the catch block to invoke